# Why should I use a private subnets to my EC2 instances

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services

I'm taking a course in AWS development. And I'm represented with the following standard diagram:
[image]

Where both the data and the EC2 instances are on private subnets. But I don't understand why I should put my EC2 instances on a private subnet and not a public if they only accept traffic via 80 and the load balancer security group. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: because if they don't connect/expose services directly to the internet they should not be in public subnet.

Comment: But if you only accept connections from the loadbalancer IP what is the security risk then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The premise is [defense in depth](https://wa.aws.amazon.com/wat.pillar.security.en.html), where you build security as a layered approach. Sure, your current approach works but with a layered approach, you try to ensure your system is covered adequately.

An instance in a private subnet will never be accessible from the Internet, regardless of any circumstance, whereas in your case, having a poorly configured security group can accidently lead to your instance from being accessible to the public. Ultimately when dealing with hundreds of resources, a segregation approach is preferred knowing that you have a failsafe.

Comment: As a developer I'm used to avoid redundancy in code at all cost, and to ensure functionality via tests. I guess the mentality regarding security and infrastructure is deferent.

Comment: And thanks for the link. I will look very much forward to read documents

Comment: you're welcome. The AWS Well-Architected Framework (the doc I linked) is an excellent read.